# .htaccess multiple rules redirect to different folder

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/drupal/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /drupal/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The folder structure is as follows

```
public_html
/apps
/drupal
```

Currently when we give www.domainname.com it redirects to drupal folder and our website is displayed. We have some apps installed in apps folder and want to access it using the url www.domainname.com/apps and when we give this it goes to drupal framework and we get page not found.

What rule should we write to that when we give /apps in the url it should get into apps folder and all other times it should go to drupal folder.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a line in the rewrite rules that you posted, but you just need to exclude the apps folder the same way you are excluding the drupal folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/drupal/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /drupal/$1 [L]
```